# Why is the "Stop" emulator option on my AVD Manager greyed out?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm a newbie in Android programming and haven't been using Android Studio for long, so I want to know if it's a bug, a "feature" (or lack thereof) or is it just my Android Studio being weird?

I should point out that I did move my Android SDK directory from the default `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` to `C:\Android\Sdk` a few days ago and a bunch of updates I can't remember. Maybe it was the cause?

If anyone has this same problem and know how to fix it, I'd appreciate it if you can share it here.
[Stop emulator option greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sg1t.png)